# Pandas error "Incompatible indexer with DataFrame" when element of DataFrame set to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

For the code

```
import pandas as pd
names = list("abc")
df = pd.DataFrame(index=names, columns=["foo"])
print(df)
for name in names:
    print("name =", name)
#    df.loc[name, "foo"] = 123
#   code works when line below is replaced by line above
    df.loc[name, "foo"] = pd.DataFrame(data=[10, 20])
```

, when I set an element of a dataframe to another dataframe, I get an error

```
    df.loc[name, "foo"] = pd.DataFrame(data=[10, 20])
    ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
```

but get no error when I set the element to a number. Why?

Comment: why would you want an element of a dataframe to be another dataframe? It is not possible in first place because dataframe is supposed to be 2 dimensional. You can construct a dataframe from another dataframe but only one dataframe not a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, but `df.loc[name, "foo"]` refers to a single line (index `a` and column `foo`) which you try to assing a dataframe with two rows (that has index `[0,1]`). What should the outcome be?

Note, you can assign an array to that element if that is what you want;

```py
names = list("abc")
df = pd.DataFrame(index=names, columns=["foo"])
name = "a"
df.loc[name, "foo"] = [10, 20]
```

**EDIT**

To add a dataframe as element you can wrap it in a list (although I think we are out in a nasty workaround):

```py
names = list("abc")
df = pd.DataFrame(index=names, columns=["foo"])
name = "a"
df.loc[name, "foo"] = [pd.DataFrame([10,20])]

print(df.loc[name,"foo"][0])

#
#     0
# 0  10
# 1  20
```

Comment: I am trying to create a dataframe of dataframes.

Comment: Please see my editted answer - although I think you should try some other solution